# c# BeginUpdateResource

Tags: c#, winapi, resources

I would like to add a string resource to an executable file *programmatically*. Just for example purposes, let's say I am trying to add a string named "String SO" which holds the value of "stringVal"

*If this helps anyone - if I were to do this through VS.net I could just right click on my Project => Resources => Add New String Resource etc..*

**I am using the following Win32 API's:**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr BeginUpdateResource(string pFileName,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool bDeleteExistingResources);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, uint lpType, uint lpName, ushort wLanguage, byte[] lpData, uint cbData);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool EndUpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, bool fDiscard);
```

So, I have found a couple of pages online but none of them seem to help me in what I am trying to do. If any of you are able to find anything I would be very grateful.

Otherwise, I would greatly appreciate any snippets that may help.
Thank you,
Evan

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3):

There is a very helpful **library for many resource-tasks** at [github](https://github.com/dblock/resourcelib).

Many classes and function do wrap those window-api-calls around `UpdateResource(...)`, etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm injecting an application byte[] as a resource to execute it on runtime. Here's my piece of code, hope it helps:

```
class AddResource
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, string lpType, string lpName, ushort wLanguage, IntPtr lpData, uint cbData);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr BeginUpdateResource(string pFileName,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool bDeleteExistingResources);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool EndUpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, bool fDiscard);
private static IntPtr ToPtr(object data)
{
    GCHandle h = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    IntPtr ptr;
    try
    {
        ptr = h.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    }
    finally
    {
        h.Free();
    }
    return ptr;

}

public static bool InjectResource(string filename, byte[] bytes, string resourceName)
{
    try
    {
        IntPtr handle = BeginUpdateResource(filename, false);
        byte[] file1 = bytes;
        IntPtr fileptr = ToPtr(file1);
        bool res = UpdateResource(handle, resourceName,
            //"RT_RCDATA",
            "0", 0, fileptr, Convert.ToUInt32(file1.Length));
        EndUpdateResource(handle, false);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output,long sz)
{
    // Insert null checking here for production
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sz];

    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

}

Here is how I use it:

```
using (Stream input = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("AppLicensing.Resources.SAppStarter.exe"))
                        using (Stream output = File.Create(outputFilePath))
                        {
                            long sz = input.Length;
                            AddResource.CopyStream(input, output, sz);
                        }
                        //inject crypted bytes
                        AddResource.InjectResource(outputFilePath, Encryptor.cryptedbytes, "RT_RCDATA");
```

And here is how I extract the resource (notice the "RT_RCDATA" -> that s the name of the resource):

```
   class ReadResource 
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindResource(IntPtr hModule, string lpName, string lpType);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SizeofResource", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern uint SizeofResource(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr hResource);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadResource", SetLastError = true)]

        private static extern IntPtr LoadResource(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr hResource);


       public static  byte[] GetFromResource(String resourceName)
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName);
            IntPtr loc = FindResource(hModule, "0", resourceName);
            uint size = SizeofResource(hModule, loc);
            IntPtr x = LoadResource(hModule, loc);
            byte[] bPtr = new byte[size];
            Marshal.Copy(x, bPtr, 0, (int)(size));
            return bPtr;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
            return null;
        }        
    }            
  }

  byte[] encryptedData = ReadResource.GetFromResource("RT_RCDATA");
```

The code gets a bit messy... hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although the author is dealing with his own issue right now, the SO question [UpdateResource function fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107637/c-sharp-updateresource-function-fails) has code snippet for using these calls.

Comment: The code snippet in the SO question you linked to is wrong and doesn't work for the following reason: it ignores the fact that UpdateResource works on blocks of up to 16 strings, not on individual strings. Those blocks have to be encoded in certain binary format - each string encoded in UTF-16 and prefixed with a 16-bit number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

The code from Samson work with String lpType, that mean you can't actually add RT_RCDATA resource either reading from it, it's only create and read lpType named "RT_RCDATA" only. If you want it to read real RT data you'll need to modify lpType from string to uint and this is RT API table:

```
private const uint RT_CURSOR = 0x00000001;
private const uint RT_BITMAP = 0x00000002;
private const uint RT_ICON = 0x00000003;
private const uint RT_MENU = 0x00000004;
private const uint RT_DIALOG = 0x00000005;
private const uint RT_STRING = 0x00000006;
private const uint RT_FONTDIR = 0x00000007;
private const uint RT_FONT = 0x00000008;
private const uint RT_ACCELERATOR = 0x00000009;
private const uint RT_RCDATA = 0x0000000a;
private const uint RT_MESSAGETABLE = 0x0000000b;
```