# C# UpdateResource function fails

Tags: c#, resources

I'm coding a simple application in C# that allows to add a resource to a .EXE file chosen by me.
The problem is that the call to UpdateResource function fails with the error 6, that according to MSDN is InvalidHandle(despite it seems that the call to BeginUpdateResource is successful) (The code is copied and pasted from a bigger file, so if some { lacks, don't care, the code compiles, but doesn't work as expected)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)] 
    static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, string lpType, string lpName, ushort wLanguage, IntPtr lpData, uint cbData);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll",SetLastError=true)]
    static extern IntPtr BeginUpdateResource(string pFileName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool bDeleteExistingResources);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll",SetLastError=true)]
    static extern bool EndUpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, bool fDiscard);

    static unsafe void  SetRes(string path)
    {
        IntPtr beginPointer = BeginUpdateResource(path, false);

        if (beginPointer != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Begin works");//This is shown

            ushort id = (ushort)Language.MakeLanguageID();
            string newMessage = "hello world!";
            Byte[] bytes = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(newMessage);
            GCHandle bHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            IntPtr ptr = bHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

            bool update = UpdateResource(beginPointer,"FILE", "Test", id,ptr, (uint)bytes.Length);

            if (update == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Update");
                EndUpdateResource(beginPointer, false);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString()); //It gives error 6
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any chance that ptr is NULL?

Comment: On what version of Windows are your executing the above code?

Comment: Change `if (beginPointer != null)` to `if (beginPointer.ToInt32() != 0)` and see if `MessageBox.Show("Begin works")` is still executed.

Comment: Also according to the community section of the documentation for [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you should capitalize `"Test"` in the call.

Comment: Should have read **upper case** `Test` in the call.

Comment: I managed to solve: in another part of the code I didn't post was opened an handle to the file used by BeginUpdateResource.After using CloseHandle() the program finally worked.
The problem is that despite the new resource is written in the exe file(I see the change by using LordPE) the C++ exe in which is written doesn't find it using FindResource, it returns me an error "Impossible to find resource". 
C#->UpdateResource(beginPointer,"#6", "TEST", id,ptr, (uint)bytes.Length);

C++ -> FindResource(NULL,"TEST","#6") ->DOESN'T WORK